# FlatUI Checkbox Table - multiple tables not checking automatically

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

This is a problem that I've been struggling with for some time now, and I can't seem to find any mention of it anywhere online. I'm using FlatUI Pro.

My context is that I'm creating an application with a large accordion, and within each segment of such there is a FlatUI checkbox table.

Now, generally when creating a single regular checkbox table, the 'toggle-all' checkbox at the top of the table will automatically check when all table rows are manually checked by a user.

However, when more than one table is present on a page (regardless of id given to checkbox elements), the 'toggle-all' checkbox on any given table will only automatically check itself when all tables have all checkboxes checked.

I'm trying to get each table to work independently of the other, as it makes no sense to have to open each accordion segment and check every table for a single table to update.

Any ideas / suggestions would be much appreciated - I'm sure it would be possible to create a custom JS function to solve this, but I'm hoping that it's just a quirk of FlatUI that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update - the FlatUI team have acknowledged this as an issue and committed a fix to the GitHub repository, as seen here: https://github.com/designmodo/Flat-UI-Pro-Support/issues/487